# How come plus, minus, muliple and division regex operators also match decimal?

Tags: regex

I tried regex 'minus', 'plus', 'multiplication' and 'division', /[*+-/]/. This regex matches all the operator signs, but it also matches decimal point. How come? How to match only these operators but not decimal?

I did it on https://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: Use ths: [*+/-] instead ( the minus '-' must be last, or it matches a range of characters)

Answer (score -1):

Inside square brackets, the construction a`-`b matches any character sorting between a and b. The regular expression `[*+-/]` matches any one of the following:

- `*` as asterisk, U+002A.
- Any character sorting between `+` (U+002B) and `/`, namely `+` (plus sign, U+2B), `,` (comma, U+002C), `-` (hyphen-minus, U+002D), `.` (period, U+002E) and `/` (solidus, U+002F).